# Copy to clipboard using javascript zeroClipboard 2.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I want to copy some text to clipboard using javascript
I have downloaded latest version of zeroClipboard 2.2

I have followed this example from http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard

Here is my html page:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath("ZeroClipboard.swf");
  //create client
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
  //event
  clip.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
   clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
  });
  clip.addEventListener('complete',function(client,text) {
   alert('copied: ' + text);
  });
  //glue it to the button
  clip.glue('copy');

 });
```

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<head>

 <script src="ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" ></script>
 
</head>

<body> 

<textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="5" cols="70">
 The David Walsh Blog is the best blog around!  MooTools FTW!
</textarea>
<br /><br />
<p><input type="button" id="copy" name="copy" value="Copy to Clipboard" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanls in advance.

Comment: my ZeroClipboard.min.js and ZeroClipboard.swf are at the same location where my html is saved.

Comment: Can you take a look to the network tab of your browser dev tools and check if all ressources are loaded (particulary .swf and .js) ?

Comment: yes, all the resources are loaded but testClipboard/ZeroClipboard.min.map is not loaded. Is there any dependency?

Comment: No .map files are only usefull [for debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/4682796)

Comment: Added ZeroClipboard.min.map in my folder now its showing undefined is not a function at this line `ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath("ZeroClipboard.swf");`

Comment: Downloaded js from [link]http://zeroclipboard.org/?version=v2.0.2&type=traditional

Answer (score 0):

The example you choose is a little bit strange with the setTimeout on the demo page. Can you try with this version ? (it comes from the official website)

The target element is set with the `data-clipboard-target` attribute.

```
<textarea id="fe_text" cols="50" rows="3">Copy me!</textarea>
<button id="d_clip_button" title="Click me to copy to clipboard." data-clipboard-target="fe_text">Copy To Clipboard...</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard($("#d_clip_button"), {
    moviePath: "ZeroClipboard.swf"
  });

  clip.on("ready", function() {
    this.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
      console.log("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"]);
    });
  });

  clip.on("error", function(event) {
    console.error('error[name="' + event.name + '"]: ' + event.message);
    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
  });
});
</script>
```

**Warning :**

Zero Clipboard might not work from local disks due to the security restrictions placed by Adobe.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450359/4682796

Comment: error[name="flash-deactivated"]: Flash is too outdated for your browser and/or is configured as click-to-activate.
This may also mean that the ZeroClipboard SWF object could not be loaded, so please check your `swfPath` configuration and/or network connectivity.
May also be attempting to run Flash in a sandboxed iframe, which is impossible.

Comment: I updated my code with setting the swf path. Can you retry please ?

Comment: Adobe Flash Player - Version: 16.0.0.305 is enabled on my chrome

Comment: Do you open the file directly in your browser ? Or do you access with localhost ? Because by me it works when I access with `http://127.0.0.1` url and it didn't work with `file://...`

Comment: I have tried this on my localhost now its giving 404 `/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1429101977830` but the .swf file is in the same location where js are stored

Comment: Can you add your file structure in your post please ?

Comment: I am using primefaces so my file structure is like this 
    -WebContent
          *resources
             -images
             -js
WEB-INF
abc.xhtml
xyz.xhtml